# GitLab.com times out on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, gitlab

I'm currently using Linux Mint 17 on my laptop and I'm almost unable to work with GitLab. The issue is pretty weird:

- GitLab.com times out every time I want to save my profile info
- GitLab.com times out every time I want to add a SSH key to my account
- GitLab.com times out when I try to ssh-keyscan it
- GitLab.com **sometimes** (but frequently) hangs up ("The remote hung up unexpectedly") when pushing or cloning.

The current way of dealing with the last problem is not convenient at all: I `push` my commits to *BitBucket*, then I take another laptop (with Windows), `pull` from *BitBucket* and then `push` to *GitLab*. Thing is, once the "remote hungs up" error appears, it doesn't go, no matter what I do on my primary laptop. And also, I prefer pushing via SSH, but I'm not able to.

I've got LAMP stack installed and running on my primary laptop, so I thought this might be a weird port issue or something. But when I connected to Internet via my iPhone's 3G, everything worked absolutely fine. At this point, I almost dialed my Internet provider support, but I remembered that everything works fine on both secondary laptop and on the Windows PC *(when running Windows)*. Also, I do have Linux (Ubuntu) on both PC and secondary laptop and the same issue is there. The only time everything worked on Linux was lubuntu on Virtual Box *(under Windows)* on my PC.

Everything works fine with other websites (GitHub, BitBucket).

Also, my `/etc/hosts` file is fine, and I do not have any firewall software running (I did check).

**tl;dr:**

- GitLab.com randomly (but *consistently*) times out when using **Linux** and my **home Internet**
- Everything's fine when using **Linux** and my iPhone's **3G Internet**
- Everything's fine when using **Windows** with my **home Internet** (did not try my iPhone 3G with Windows, as I don't see a reason to)

So the question is, what am I doing wrong on Linux?